# Finding an inner product with respect to which a specific basis is orthonormal

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a questions. How to find scalar product for whom basis $\mathbb{R}^2$, consisting of vectors $(3,1),(1,2)$ is orthonormal.

Comment: Do you mean "basis"?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1819436/265466.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

You just need to find any inner product which satisfies $$\left(\begin{matrix}3&1\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}a&b\\c&d\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}1\\2\end{matrix}\right)=0$$ and the reverse.

Then you can deal with normalising afterwards.

Comment: You can use $c=b$ to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Every scalar product $(\cdot,\cdot)_A$ on $\mathbb R^2$ has an associated symmetric matrix $A$ such that $(\mathbf v,\mathbf w)_A=\mathbf v^TA\mathbf w$. Let $B$ be the matrix with the given basis vectors as its columns. The condition that this basis is orthonormal relative to $(\cdot,\cdot)_A$is equivalent to $B^TAB=I$, therefore the matrix of this inner product must be $A=(B^{-1})^T(B^{-1})=(BB^T)^{-1}$.